# how to content file pdf in iframe in center when window.print

Tags: javascript, html, laravel, iframe, laravel-blade

case in chrome : so when I call window.print() the pdf file looks a bit tilted and not neat or middle position, but when I several times ctrl + p (window.print()) it's just right.

code in blade laravel:

```
<div class="col-12 mt-2 secondAppend">
  @foreach ($file_penawarans as $item)
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
         <iframe src="{{ $item['file_penawaran'] }}#toolbar=0&navpanes=0&pagemode=none&scrollbar=0" style="width: 100%; align-content: center;" frameborder="0" height="1000px">
         </iframe>
      </div>
     </div>
  @endforeach
</div>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3zUDX.png)

**I want it to be neat the first time I call window print.**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IUH0u.png)

Comment: Have you try do ```@media print{..}``` in css?